# Continuously backs up same files as if this was the first time doing a backup

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine

On Snow Leopard 10.6.8, TimeMachine keeps backing up the same files over and over again, as if they were not backed up the first time. As a result, each time I get a full backup of 300 GB!

I checked the Backups.backupdb folder tree and looked at "snapshots by date" (e.g. 2012-07-06-201030). What is strange is the files TimeMachine backs up have exactly the same MD5 checksum for each backup.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you looking at "snapshots by date" if just browsing in Finder then they will appear even if not backed up again

Comment: Can you post the console logs from `backupd` the next time Time Machine does a full backup without inheriting files from the previous one?